# Android - Kitkat VideoView can't play HLS

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-4.4-kitkat, http-live-streaming

I tried to make a simple app using *VideoView* to play a fullscreen HLS,
This is the code :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class FullScreenActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
    private VideoView fullVideoView;
    private String URL = "http://win.stream.netmedia.co.id/live/nettv_low/index.m3u8";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
        fullVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vv);
        fullVideoView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        fullVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(URL));
        fullVideoView.requestFocus();
        // fullVideoView.start();  <-- I have tried it, but still not work
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        // This code will start/paused the videoview when videoview is touched
        if (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            if (fullVideoView.isPlaying()) {
                fullVideoView.pause();
            } else {
                fullVideoView.start();
            }
        return true;
    }

}
```

This code works perfectly on Jelly Bean.
But for some reason, this code doesn't work on KitKat.
I tried this code on Jelly Bean and KitKat at the same device.
Can someone explain why this code doesn't work on KitKat?
Below is the log file, it keep spamming like that until I close the app.

```
01-14 18:15:58.502: I/SurfaceView(25875): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
01-14 18:15:58.504: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 1280.00, 736.00) opaque 1 <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.505: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): finish <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.518: I/SurfaceView(25875): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
01-14 18:15:58.521: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 1280.00, 736.00) opaque 1 <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.522: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): finish <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.534: I/SurfaceView(25875): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
01-14 18:15:58.536: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 1280.00, 736.00) opaque 1 <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.537: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): finish <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.550: I/SurfaceView(25875): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
01-14 18:15:58.552: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 1280.00, 736.00) opaque 1 <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.553: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): finish <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.566: I/SurfaceView(25875): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
01-14 18:15:58.568: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 1280.00, 736.00) opaque 1 <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.569: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): finish <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.582: I/SurfaceView(25875): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
01-14 18:15:58.584: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 1280.00, 736.00) opaque 1 <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.585: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): finish <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.598: I/SurfaceView(25875): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
01-14 18:15:58.600: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 1280.00, 736.00) opaque 1 <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.601: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): finish <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.614: I/SurfaceView(25875): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
01-14 18:15:58.617: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 1280.00, 736.00) opaque 1 <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.618: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): finish <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.630: I/SurfaceView(25875): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
01-14 18:15:58.632: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 1280.00, 736.00) opaque 1 <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.633: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): finish <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.647: I/SurfaceView(25875): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
01-14 18:15:58.649: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 1280.00, 736.00) opaque 1 <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.650: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): finish <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.662: I/SurfaceView(25875): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
01-14 18:15:58.664: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 1280.00, 736.00) opaque 1 <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.665: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): finish <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.678: I/SurfaceView(25875): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
01-14 18:15:58.680: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 1280.00, 736.00) opaque 1 <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.681: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): finish <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.694: I/SurfaceView(25875): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
01-14 18:15:58.696: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 1280.00, 736.00) opaque 1 <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.697: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): finish <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.710: I/SurfaceView(25875): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
01-14 18:15:58.713: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 1280.00, 736.00) opaque 1 <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.713: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): finish <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.726: I/SurfaceView(25875): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
01-14 18:15:58.728: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 1280.00, 736.00) opaque 1 <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.729: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): finish <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.743: I/SurfaceView(25875): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
01-14 18:15:58.745: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 1280.00, 736.00) opaque 1 <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.746: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): finish <0x6567e698>
01-14 18:15:58.758: I/SurfaceView(25875): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
01-14 18:15:58.760: D/OpenGLRenderer(25875): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 1280.00, 736.00) opaque 1 <0x6567e698>
```

Comment: Found any solution to this problem ?